# SQL need assistance

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Hi all so im stuck on this sql query question: write an sql statement that displays details of session (id and date) that shows crime movies. You must use join to obtain the answer.

I have a table for session with an id column and a date column and i have a movie table that has an moviegenre column with 'crime' under it. I was wondering how i could construct this. I found an example of one:

```
Select orders.orderid, 
       customers.customername, 
       orders.orderdate 
from orders 
inner join customers 
    on orders.customerid = customers.customerid;
```

from [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), but am unsure on how to use this so help answer my question. Also is there a way of doing is problem with using a sub query instead

thank you!

Comment: Please, don't write in UPPER CASE ALL THE TIME.

Comment: You will need to find the columns that link the two tables (the columns upon which to join).

Comment: show the schema of both tables

Answer (score 0):

```
Select s.id, 
       s.date,        
from Session s 
inner join Movie m 
    on m.commoncol = s.commomcol
 where m.MovieGenre like 'crime';
```

commomcol represents the mutual column between the tables. Name of the commoncol can be different in both tables.

Hope it helps!!